# Match and pull data from different colums and rows

Tags: excel-formula

I am working with two lists that contain stock data of two locations. The products are not on the same rows though, which makes checking stock levels for the two locations difficult.

I would like to match the products in the two lists (location A: columns A-D and location B: Columns F-I). Then pull the stock level from Location B (Column I) and display it in Column E.

So for example

Product number ABC101 has a stock level of 5,00 at location A (cell D6). At Location B it has a stock level of 2,00 (cell I8). I would like to display the level from cell I8 into cell E6. Please see the images.

I have tried to work with VLOOKUP and INDEX but I am totally stuck... Hope an expert can help me sort this out.

Thanks so much!
Syl

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you tried: `=VLOOKUP(A1,F:I,4,FALSE)`?

Comment: I have tried variations of a combined Index-match formula, but none worked. I have tried out your formula but it does not return the correct stock levels out of column I. Instead it returns a 0,00 result.

Comment: Sorry the `A1` should have been `A6`: `=VLOOKUP(A6,F:I,4,FALSE)`

Comment: Works!! Thanks so much Scott!